# Writing a link to web page with javascript fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, links

I'm an Expression Engine newbie, so this might have some obvious fix in EE land.  This javascript code works fine when I put it on a page that is not rendered by Expression Engine:

```
 $(myDivName).append("<a href='http://www.foobar.com'>click here</a>");
```

And this works fine on an Expression engine page:

```
$(myDivName).append("<img style='margin: 2px 30px;' src='http://www.foobar.com/image.jpg' width='225' height='275' align='left'>" ");
```

However, the first snippet of javascript above does not work on an EE page- I get a javascript error at the time the page the is loaded saying "unidentified symbol":

```
$(myDivName).append("<a href='http://www.foobar.com'>click here</a>");
```

If I look with Chrome inspector, I can see that EE changed the url to wrap it in what seems to be a redirect.  Is there some formatting I need to put around dynamically written links to get them to work?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Where is your javascript being output, from a template or a channel entry field? You say it's dynamically written, so if it's on a template can you include more of the tags that output the problem js?

Comment: Please could you share the output from the Chrome inspector please? What add-ons (if any) are installed? Do you have any browser extensions that could manipulate URLs?